# Slack Blocks - Email input with dispatch action is not dispatching

Tags: slack, slack-block-kit

I want to show a Slack input with blocks and have an email input that fires the action when someone enters an email and presses enter.

This renders correctly, but the action firing is not working (nor do I see `press 'enter' to submit` like I do for a plain text box)

For some reason, if I change the `element.type` from `email_text_input` to `plain_text_input` it works.

How do I make Slack show an email input that will fire an action when "enter" is pressed?

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Enter email",
                "emoji": false
            },
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "confirm-block",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "example@example.com",
                    "emoji": false
                },
                "focus_on_load": true
            },
            "dispatch_action": true,
            "optional": false
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Enter email",
                "emoji": false
            },
            "element": {
                "type": "email_text_input",
                "action_id": "confirm-block",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "example@example.com",
                    "emoji": false
                },
                "focus_on_load": false
            },
            "dispatch_action": true,
            "optional": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the rendering in the block kit builder:

[image: Rendering of above code]